# Intent putExtra from two Activities

Tags: android

Hello I hope you can help me:

I have three Activities: `Activity1 --> Activity2 --> Activity3`

In Activity1 and 2 I have an Intent, which put a string from an EditText Extra.

And in Activity3 I want to receive BOTH strings, but as I try Activity3 only receive the Intent from Activity2 (the previous activity).

Here the code from Activity1:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity2.class);
    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String name = et1.getText().toString();

        if (name.length() == 0) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(
                    R.string.error_name_missing).setNeutralButton(
                    R.string.error_ok,
                    null).show();
            return;
        }

        intent.putExtra(konto_name1, name);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

From Activity2:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity3.class); 
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        String value = et2.getText().toString();

        if (value.length() == 0) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(
                    R.string.error_value_missing).setNeutralButton(
                    R.string.error_ok,
                    null).show();
            return;
        }

        intent.putExtra(start_value1, value);
        startActivity(intent);      
    }
```

Comment: use sharedpreference or again send same value from activity2

Comment: Can you show me the code for getting `konto_name1` in Activity 2 pls

Comment: Did you solve it or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your second activity code like this. See in second activity you have a different intent. It has no relation between the intent from 1st activity. So you need to take the value from 1st activity intent to 2nd activity intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity3.class);



EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

String value = et2.getText().toString();

if (value.length() == 0) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(
            R.string.error_value_missing).setNeutralButton(
            R.string.error_ok,
            null).show();
    return;
}

intent.putExtra(start_value1, value);

intent.putExtra(konto_name1,getIntent().getStringExtra(konto_name1));//Add this line in your code
startActivity(intent);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your First Activity intent in `Acitivity2.java` and again pass it to `Activity3.java`

**Activity1.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity2.class);
 intent.putExtra(konto_name1, name);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2.java**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity3.class);
final String firstActivityValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    intent.putExtra(start_value1, value);
    intent.putExtra(start_value2, firstActivityValue);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can get both values in `Activity3.java` using getIntent().

Hope it helps.

Comment: @JonasW. If you solve then accept answer so that it will helps other developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass from Intent to Intent, as the other answers discuss. However you can also use `SharedPreferences` to make it easier to work with.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString(konto_name1, name)
edit.commit();
```

Or if you wanted it as a one-liner:

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(konto_name1, name).commit();`

Then instead of getting the string from the Intent, just use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String newString = prefs.getString(konto_name1, "");
```

That'll do what you want, without having to keep track of strings passed from Intent to Intent, which I used to find annoying at best.

Again, above as a one-liner:

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(konto_name1, "");`

You should do the same with the String in Activity2. Don't worry, every time your item is clicked in Activity(1/2) the preference will be overwritten. Note that the second parameter in `getString()` is a default String in case the one you want to retrieve doesn't exist.